# Hibernate Unidirectional Mapping with Composite Primary Key

Tags: hibernate, composite-primary-key

I have a problem when I wanted to add Student to another sport, instead of saving the additional sport , it overwrites the existing one.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="STUDENT_ID")
private int studentId;

@Column(name="\"ACTIVE\"")
private boolean active;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "STUDENT_SPORTS", 
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "STUDENT_ID") }, 
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "SPORTS_ID") })
private List<Sports> sports= new ArrayList<Sports>();

public Student () {
}

public int getStudentId() {
    return studentId;
}

public void setStudentId(int studentId) {
    this.studentId= studentId;
}
```

My Output should be the following in Student_sports :

Student_id sports_id

5            5

5            6

But instead the output is like this in Student_sports table :

Student_id sports_id

5              6

Comment: You missed to use `@Unique` or in `@Column (unique = true)` for your `studentId` that's why he overwrites the existing one.

Answer (score 0):

Here with `unique = true` :

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="STUDENT_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 5) // <= You can also add some details more like this 
private int studentId;

@Column(name="\"ACTIVE\"")
private boolean active;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "STUDENT_SPORTS", 
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "STUDENT_ID") }, 
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "SPORTS_ID") })
private List<Sports> sports= new ArrayList<Sports>();

public Student () {
}

public int getStudentId() {
    return studentId;
}

public void setStudentId(int studentId) {
    this.studentId= studentId;
}
```

Can you try it please ?